# Reissue ids to records with duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-query-store

We have a CRM DB which for the last 6 weeks has been creating duplicate CaseID's

I need to go in and give new case id's int he 20000000 range to all of the duplicates.

So I have found all the duplicates like this

```
SELECT CaseNumber, 
    COUNT(CaseNumber) AS NumOccurrences
FROM Goldmine.dbo.cases
WHERE CaseNumber > 9000000
GROUP BY CaseNumber
HAVING ( COUNT(CaseNumber) > 1 )
```

Which brought back this.

[image: query results]

I now need to renumber each one of these like so 20000001, 20000002, etc etc

Any help would be great.

Comment: What have you tried so far, why didn't it work? What RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: @ChrisLeonard . . . Based on the "dbo" and three-part naming, I am assuming you are using SQL Server and I removed the MySQL tag.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @ChrisLeonard...While re-numbering the duplicates do you need the values to be contiguous(eg: say you had values (8,8,8,9,9,10), and after update is (8,9,10,12,13,15) acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are using SQL Server.  So you can use updatable CTEs:

```
WITH dups as (
      SELECT c.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CaseNumber) as seqnum
      FROM Goldmine.dbo.cases c
      WHERE CaseNumber > 9000000
     ),
     toupdate as (
      SELECT d.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CaseNumber ORDER BY CaseNumber) as inc
      FROM dups d
      WHERE seqnum > 1
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET CaseNumber = 20000000 + inc;
```

The first subquery identifies the duplicates by enumerating them.  Presumably, you don't want the "first" one to change.  So the second CTE selects only the real duplicates and assigns a sequential number.  The outer `update` uses that to assign the new number.

Comment: Hi thanks for the fast help, this is great what you have written and has renumbered all of them but its kept the duplicates. I want 0 duplicates at the end so the duplicates also need renumbering and give NEW numbers also please.

Comment: As you can see here I still have lots of duplicates against the new numbers. https://ibb.co/GCLKr0s

Comment: Hi, Sorry maybe I am confusing you, I now have lots of case 20000001. The query runs but I want it to find all duplicates > 9000000 and then renumber them from 20000000 upwards. I should be left with 0 duplicates but I still have thousands. Sorry to be a pain I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: I am so close to doing this with all the help I have been given by you guys. I am sorry for not understanding so much. How can I put this all together to do this to my database as above...

do I have to combine to 2 queries?

Comment: anyone? Can you please help me combine this to work?

Comment: @ChrisLeonard . . . Oops . . . there shouldn't be a `partition by` in the second CTE.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of the data you have got overlaps in numbers because there are records which overlap with the "updated" values if we are to increment by 1.
Here is a way to fix this,

```
with data
  as (select *
            ,count(*) over(partition by x) as cnt
            ,row_number() over(order by x) as rnk
        from t
      )
update data
   set x = x+rnk;
```

Initial record set

```
+-----------+
| orig_data |
+-----------+
|  10000009 |
|  10000009 |
|  10000009 |
|  10000009 |
|  10000010 |
|  10000010 |
|  10000011 |
+-----------+
```

After update

```
+-----------+
| after_upd |
+-----------+
|  10000010 |
|  10000011 |
|  10000012 |
|  10000014 |
|  10000015 |
|  10000017 |
+-----------+
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c4ea8335abb074b8c0143e2f7c767f04